# does auth0 can be intergrated with self hosted cms

Tags: gatsby, auth0, directus

I want to make an auth to GatsbyJs and the one that always pops up is auth0, so I am wondering does making auth0 with Directus cms possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Auth Adapter for v8... I believe all OAuth will be supported out of the box for v9.

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/auth-providers.html